# Approximating the integral of an $L^1$ function by the integral over a finite set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $f\in L^1(\mu)$. Show that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $A\in\mathcal A$ with $\mu(A)<\infty$ and $|\int_A f\ \mathsf d\mu - \int f\ \mathsf d\mu| < \varepsilon. $

I tried using $A=\{x\in\Omega : |f(x)|>\varepsilon\} $ which has finite measure (as else the integral of $f$ would be $+\infty$) but could not see how to conclude. Hints, as opposed to a full answer, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A=\{x:|f(x)| >\epsilon\}$. Since $\int |f| \geq \int_A |f| \geq \epsilon \mu (A)$ we see that $\mu (A) <\infty$. Use DCT to complete the proof. To avoid DCT note that $\{x:|f(x)| > \frac 1 n\}$ increases to $\{x:|f(x)| > 0\}=\{x:f(x) \neq 0\}$ as $n$ increases to $\infty$. This should be enough of a hint.

Comment: The question is asked in a text before the dominated convergence theorem is introduced, so presumably there is another way to show this.

Comment: How about Monotone Convergence Theorem? Can I use that?

Comment: Yes, monotone convergence is covered before this exercise.

Comment: Thanks, I see now. Brushing up on my measure theory and I'm a bit rusty :)